# How to get git scm url for a Jenkins job with groovy

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins

Is there a way to get the scm git repo url string inside a Jenkins job with groovy?

Comment: Probably it is. Can You clarify the question a bit? Maybe add an example?

Comment: There is a git repository url defined in the build job scm. I only want to know this entry. Maybe something with job.scm.location.

Comment: import jenkins.model.*;
    import hudson.model.*;
    import hudson.tasks.*;
    import hudson.plugins.git.*;
    
    for(project in Hudson.instance.items) {
      scm = project.scm;
      if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
          println("SCM " + scm.toString() + " for project " +  project);    
      } 
    }

Answer (score 6):

```
import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.tasks.*;
import hudson.plugins.git.*;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RemoteConfig;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.URIish;

for(project in Hudson.instance.items) {
  scm = project.scm;
  if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
    for (RemoteConfig cfg : scm.getRepositories()) {
      for (URIish uri : cfg.getURIs()) {
        println("SCM " + uri.toString() + " for project " + project);    
      }
    } 
  }  
}
```

Comment: Great! As far as I see it wasn't that difficult!

Answer (score 2):

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each{
scm = it.scm;
project = it;
if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
    scm.getRepositories().each{
        it.getURIs().each{
            println("SCM " + it.toString() + " in " + project);
        }
    }
}}
```