# Variable of selected source code management in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a variable in Jenkins, which I can use, to get which SCM is configured for the job?

i.e Git, Subversion, etc...

I am hoping to have this information at the time of build like with msbuild

I am using SVN_URL and GIT_URL at the moment. Want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: You mean, the scm is configured for checking out your Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your msbuild script can access [environment variables set by Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project), as you mention.

If you see a non-empty environment variable named:

- `GIT_COMMIT`: that means there is a Git repository associated to your job
- `SVN_REVISION`: that means there is a SVN repository associated to your job
- `CVS_BRANCH`: that means there is a CVS repository associated to your job

---

More complex approach:

[As in this groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752159/6309), you can check:

- if there is any scm defined for a job

  ```
  scm = project.scm;
  ```
- if that scm is Git or another SCM (like the [Mercurial one](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialSCM.java))

  ```
  if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
  ```

From there, your [groovy script can inject in your job a new environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936515/6309) (with the [JENKINS EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin))

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def pa = new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("SCM", "Git")
])
build.addAction(pa)
```

---

The [OP Idothisallday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821005/idothisallday) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481890/variable-of-selected-source-code-management-in-jenkins/43487328?noredirect=1#comment74107113_43487328):

> How is above var better than using `SVN_URL` and `GIT_URL`?

This is the same general idea. The second approach let you define your own value), but to the general question "Want to know if there is a better way.": no, not really (that I know of).

Comment: Hi @Vonc, i have added more context, need it in msbuild and not groovy script thanks

Comment: @Idothisallday you can still use groovy as a pre-build step. The rest can use msbuild command, since groovy set an environment variable that can then ben accessed/read by the msbuild process.

Comment: Ahh, I will give it a try.Is project.scm not available just like other jenkins variables?

Comment: I am still not sure, how is above var better than using SVN_URL and GIT_URL.

Comment: @Idothisallday it is the same general idea (the second approach let you define your own value), but to your general question "Want to know if there is a better way.": no, not really (that I know of)

Comment: Thanks VonC, if you can add this context to your answer (for completeness and others who may search for this), i will accept it. As i have not seen any other answer.